# WSO2 integration with TCP and Restservice

Tags: wso2

I am new to WSO2 and we are planing to use WSO2 in our product. Our requirement is to communicate with other system through TCP(socket) and rest web services. I did not find any help regrading to my requirement.
I need a step by step guide or any tutorial about my requirements or any sample projet. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use WSO2 ESB to connect systems with TCP and HTTP(rest). You can go through WSO2 ESB documents and find enough samples on that. TCP[1][2], rest api[3]. If you are going to manage the rest apis then you can use the WSO2 API Manager[4]

[1]https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Setting+Up+the+ESB+Samples#SettingUptheESBSamples-ConfiguringWSO2ESBtousetheTCPtransport

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=33136069

[3] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Using+REST+with+APIs

[4] https://docs.wso2.com/api-manager-documentation